# Is it possible for features to be lists for clustering algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning

Here is my usecase:

I have web resources and for each resource a set of views of it. It's coming from web navigation, so resources are what you visit and views are actual visits.

For each view, I have information about the location, the time of the day the view was made, and I can get information like the total number of views and the time passed on this resource.

I want to find different patterns in this information, to determine user profiles. If, for each resource I had only one view, it could be easy to cluster them, but as I do have a number of views, is there a way I can use this information to better cluster resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you wish to cluster the resources based on the views they have. To do this, you may want to make a feature vector based on the statistics of the views. For example, your feature vector can include: total number of views, std dev of the locations of viewers, mean time of day of views, age of resource, etc. You can then feed these feature vector into a clustering algorithm. The exact features you want to use will depend and your use of the clusters. If you want to have cluster reflect the content of resources and the resources are text based, then I would recommend using a [bag of words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag_of_words_model) as well.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I'm computing stdev, avg and other metrics and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what exactly you are asking. Yes, [feature vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_vector) are widely used in machine learning algorithms.